# Xamarin App using same credentials used for web site login

Tags: xamarin, credentials

I have my web site with API. I want to build a Xamarin mobile app and call this API. How can I get my users to login on the mobile app with same credentials they use on website. How can I achieve this in Xamarin?

Comment: You need to create a web api and consume it in your xamarin app using `HttpClient` or any other network library available

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How can I achieve this in Xamarin?

**You don't!** Your Xamarian app runs only on the users phone. And the phone shouldn't have access to the database to validate credentials.

> How can I achieve this in general?

This assumes, your website has a procedure/class/whatever that is responsible for validating user credentials and returning session tokens. In this case, simply build an api endpoint, that accepts the credentials and uses the same login code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, no client (Mobile App or Web App) should have direct access to your database, especially in production.

*You may consider it as a work-around in case of home-work or testing purposes.*

Answering your question, as you mention you already have an API up & running that you are calling (consuming) from your Web App.

All you have to do is consume the same API from your Xamarin App (I am assuming it's a Xamarin.Forms app) using
 `HttpClient` (or other similar classes & libraries) that accepts/returns data in
 JSON/XML formats which you need to serialize/deserialize for internal
 usage.

These links could be helpful:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Answer (score 0):

Well the fast answer here is to consume a web api. But can you do that? More on this topic you can find at xamarin documentation.

You should give a try to take a look at these examples provided my xamarin documentation : [consuming rest services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/)  and [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) is pretty useful too.

Also there is some pretty interesting tutorials series provided by Houssem Dellai in youtube. He also explains how to create a very simple web api and how to consume it.(Login involved) [Click here for more details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UToBKlnig4M&list=PLpbcUe4chE78YvgIMtmgNEmRGyGJcsQdF)

If you are looking at more detailed example I can provide you with one. :)